# «Invalid value» error while brackets in chrome.commands

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need hotkeys `Alt + ]` and `Alt + [`. I have `manifest.json` like:

```
{
    ...
    "commands": {
        "nextTrack": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+]"
            },
            "description": "Next track"
        },
        "previousTrack": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+["
            },
            "description": "Previous track"
        },
        "toggle": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+P"
            },
            "description": "Toggle pause"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

When I enable my extension I get:

```
Could not load extension from '~/project'. 
Invalid value for 'commands[1].default': Alt+].
```

What is way to use that hotkeys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only uppercase letters (A-Z) and digits (0-9) are valid values, as you can see by looking at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/command.cc&l=95&q=kInvalidKeyBinding&sq=package%3achromium) of the [`chrome.commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) API.

If you want to use other characters, inject a content script in every page which binds a `keydown` event:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (!event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && event.which === 80/*P*/) {
        // Dispatch a custom message, handled by your extension
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Alt+P');
    }
}, true); // <-- True is important
```

### Disadvantages of this method

- Keyboard focus **must** be within a page where the content script is activated. The shortcut will fail if you're inside the Developer tools, omnibar, etc.
- Even if you use `<all_urls>` as a [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), it won't work on non http(s) / file / ftp(s) schemes like `chrome:`, `data:`, `chrome-extension:`, `about:` or the Chrome Web store.
- You can run into problems with detecting the `[` character, if the keyboard layout does not support it, or uses a different key code.
- There's no built-in support for customizing this shortcut (as a user, visit `chrome://extensions/`, scroll to the bottom and click on "Configure commands" to change the extension's shortcut).

I suggest to pick a different shortcut, or change the way how your extension is controlled (through a [page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html) / [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) popup, for instance).

Comment: @VladislavPolukhin Depends on what you want to achieve. I assumed that the message had to be directed to the background page, because `chrome.commands` would usually trigger a `chrome.commands.onCommand` event which can only be handled by the background page. For injecting code in every page, see [the documentation for content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).