# chrome.commands API: how to specify shortcuts involving `.` (dot) and `,` (comma)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension development:

Using the new chrome.commands API, which lets you specify global keyboard shortcuts handled by the extension, how can I specify shortcuts involving `,` and `.` in `manifest.json`?

E.g: Specifying `Alt+M` works fine but `Alt+.` leads to an error about the value being invalid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [«Invalid value» error while brackets in chrome.commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034279/invalid-value-error-while-brackets-in-chrome-commands)

Comment: The answer on that page does not work for me. My specific need is to allow the user to invoke the shortcut even on tabs without any content script, like the "new tab" tab, or a tab where the server did not send any response, or the chrome://settings tab, etc.
Is only allowing A-Z and 0-9 expected behavior? If so, why?, and  isn't it documented?

Comment: The first line of that answer is the answer to your question: There is *no way* to use dots or commas as a shortcut, because only alphanumeric characters are allowed (the link to Chromium's C++ source code is provided in that answer). This unfortunate observation is followed by an alternative (using a content script) and a discussion of its effectiveness.

Comment: I agree. Feel free to delete/merge. Do you have thoughts on: is only allowing A-Z and 0-9 expected behavior? If so, why?, and isn't it documented?

Comment: I don't know the motivation behind restricting to A-Z 0-9 (probably because some subset of keys had to be chosen, and a-z 0-9 are guaranteed to exist on keyboards). The restriction is not mentioned in the official documentation, but it is apparent from the source code, and I have documented it on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Yeah, but I was wondering if it could be some sort of oversight, and if so, would raising this this as a bug/feature request make sense? (thanks for the unofficial documentation ;))

Comment: You can star the following issue if you want to receive updates on the progress: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it worked differently before, but it is (now) possible to create shortcuts involving . ("Period") and , ("Comma") as in the following examples:

```
"Alt+Comma"
"Alt+Period"
```